# Convert milliseconds column to HH:mm:ss:ms datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column containing the number of milliseconds passed (starting from 0, not epoch)

```
           time
0           NaN
1        4067.0
2     3444053.0
3    50477685.0
4    60476311.0
5    70475303.0
6    80475303.0
```

I'd like to convert this column to a HH:mm:ss:ms format. Is this possible? I've found that using *pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')* always converts the column to epoch.

```
                    time
0                    NaT
1    1971-04-14 02:27:33
```

Whereas I would like something along the lines of:

```
            time
0            NaT
1    00:00:04:67
```

Comment: I noticed you've unaccepted. Anything I can help with? If you have further clarification on my answer, please ask. From what I see it seems to have solved your problem.

Comment: Re-accepted, sorry, I briefly thought it wasn't working but that wasn't the case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want `to_timedelta` here.

```
df.time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='ms')
df.time 

0               NaT
1   00:00:04.067000
2   00:57:24.053000
3   14:01:17.685000
4   16:47:56.311000
5   19:34:35.303000
6   22:21:15.303000
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

To get back to square one, use `df.total_seconds`:

```
df.time.dt.total_seconds() * 1000

0           NaN
1        4067.0
2     3444053.0
3    50477685.0
4    60476311.0
5    70475303.0
6    80475303.0
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can separate the time portion using

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms').dt.time
```

the result will be

```
0                NaN
1    00:00:04.067000
2    00:57:24.053000
3    14:01:17.685000
4    16:47:56.311000
5    19:34:35.303000
6    22:21:15.303000
Name: time, dtype: object
```

to get the close to the desired output

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],
             unit='ms').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f').str[:-3]
```

this will display the micro seconds using `strftime` and slicing will convert to milliseconds.

Here is the output of `df['time']`

```
0                
1    00:00:04:067
2    00:57:24:053
3    14:01:17:685
4    16:47:56:311
5    19:34:35:303
6    22:21:15:303
Name: time, dtype: object
```